# wordpress load different menu based on url

Tags: php, wordpress

I bought a basic WPML plugin yesterday, but I still have a problem regarding the different menus that I need to show according to the url, so, assuming that my primary menu name is "primary" and the second is "secundary", i put a condition on the top of the page. When the url contains "/en/" the "secundary" menu has to be loaded, otherwise the "primary" has to be loaded.

It seems that the following logic

```
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  

if (preg_match('/\/en\//',$host))
{
    wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'secundary'));  
} else {
    wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'primary')); 
}
```

It doesn't work. Maybe there's something about wp_nav_menu() that I don't know.

Can you help me to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check REQUEST URI part of $_SERVER array

```
<?php 
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/en/') !== false) {
//Set second menu here
} else {
//Use primary`
}
```

But you also have to register menu for WP: https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus

Comment: Now I understand why i couldn't see the Menu submenu in the Admin panel :-) I forgot to implement that function in my theme. Thanks a lot